# Different sizes of images in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview, screen-density

I'm trying to create main activity in my application using GridView. I need to have a grid 3x3. Every cell contains ImageView (icons for different actions). All images must have the same size. And my question is: what sizes of image I must use? I watched tutorial and found a table with sizes for different resolutions and density. But I didn't understand. For instance, I have mdpi density and screen size 480*800. Does it mean that I should use icons 160*266 for this screen? And what sizes should be for other densities and screen sizes? How can I calculate them?

Comment: You can use the dimens folder for the different resolution of devices..

Comment: Yes, I can. But my question is: what physical sizes of images should I use?

Comment: You need to tale help of designer in this case...You have to specify the resolution to them and he will tell , you the height and width of the image

Comment: For me, it's a main problem)) I cannot unserstand, what should I say to him? Only screen sizes (small, normal, large, extra-large), without densities? I can't get relation between density and screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most asked question, you can search for more details, but let me give you briefly how it works.

MDPI is considered as the base line and following are the scales

```
MDPI    - X1
HDPI    - X1.5
XHDPI   - X2
XXHDPI  - X3
XXXHDPI - X4
```

Now you must be thinking what is this.

Since you want to have 3X3 grid with cell of equal size, you can consider the following.
In general mdpi screen size is 360 X 640, so each image size will be 120dp X 212dp Approx.

```
For mdpi screen, your Image size should be 120px X 212px
For hdpi screen, your Image size should be 180px X 318px
For xhdpi screen, your Image size should be 240px X 424px
For xxdpi screen, your Image size should be 360px X 636px
For xxxdpi screen, your Image size should be 480px X 848px
```

Now where you should place these images?

**Project -> app -> src -> main -> res**

Here, create folders with name `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc, and place respective images in these folders.

Thats it for supporting multiple screen densities.

> According to docs, MDPI and HDPI screen sizes are given considering
>   their aspect ratio to 3:4, but since most of the users have HD
>   devices with aspect ratio of 9:16, you can consider the most standard
>   screen size in Market i.e. 1080 X 1920 which corresponds to XXHDPI and
>   acts as baseline to make the assumption of considering MDPI to be 360
>   X 640. For high quality apps, trade off has to be made for lower
>   devices since most of the  existing users have XXHDPI or higher
>   devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually I want to know, what physical size should I use as baseline? I want to have 3x3 grid of images, where all cells have the same size. What physical size should have this image in mdpi density? (480/3 x 800/3)? And should I use screen size?

Comment: Thanks! But where have you found 360x640? In Android docs, they give 320x480 for mdpi normal screen.. For hdpi, they give 480x800,and your image size 180x318 requires 540x960 size.

Comment: Sometimes you get the details from experience more than the doc, Standard workable screen size is 1080 X 1920 which corresponds to XXHDPI, since XXHDPI is 3XMDPI, we assume MDPI to be 360 X 640. Since this screen has to be divided into 9 equal imageviews, you have 360/3  = 120 for width and 640/3 ~ 212 for height as baseline. What you said is absolutely correct, but sometimes you have to make adjustments to target higher users than those who are still using low res devices. Honestly speaking, I stopped adding MDPI folder itself in my projects because it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you for your help!